# JanusGraph Server XML Configuration

Tags: graph-databases, tinkerpop, janusgraph

Anyone knows how to configure the username and password for janusgraph server. So any http/socket send to this janusgraph server require authentication.

Thank You

Answer (score 2):

JanusGraph packages TinkerPop's Gremlin Server, so to configure authentication you can simply follow the Gremlin Server's instructions for doing so. The basic steps would be to modify the server yaml file to include the following:

```
authentication: {
  authenticator: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.auth.SimpleAuthenticator,
  config: {
    credentialsDb: conf/credentials.properties}}
```

which sets up a "simple" authentication system that uses a local `Graph` instance configured by `conf/credentials.properties` to house username/passwords. Obviously, you could write a more advanced `Authenticator` if you'd like and use that instead - the `SimpleAuthenticator` is really just a  reference implementation to get people started. Here's an example that uses TinkerGraph as the target database for the credentials:

```
gremlin.graph=org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.tinkergraph.structure.TinkerGraph
gremlin.tinkergraph.vertexIdManager=LONG
gremlin.tinkergraph.graphLocation=data/credentials.kryo
gremlin.tinkergraph.graphFormat=gryo
```

but it could obviously be any `Graph` you wanted to use.

To setup the usernames and passwords in that graph you would need to use the Credentials DSL typically executed as an administration task through the Gremlin Console. You would do something like:

```
gremlin> :plugin use tinkerpop.credentials
==>tinkerpop.credentials activated
gremlin> graph = ... // create your graph instance for usernames/passwords
...
gremlin> credentials = credentials(graph)
==>CredentialGraph{graph=tinkergraph[vertices:0 edges:0]}
gremlin> credentials.createUser("stephen","password")
==>v[0]
gremlin> credentials.createUser("daniel","better-password")
==>v[3]
gremlin> credentials.createUser("marko","rainbow-dash")
==>v[6]
gremlin> credentials.findUser("marko").properties()
==>vp[password->$2a$04$lBXMnKWtLB...]
==>vp[username->marko]
gremlin> credentials.countUsers()
==>3
gremlin> credentials.removeUser("daniel")
==>1
gremlin> credentials.countUsers()
==>2
```

Start Gremlin Server with that configuration and authentication should be enabled.

These steps are described in more detail in the TinkerPop [reference documentation](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#security). I'd suggest that you [download](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/downloads.html) Gremlin Server on its own and examine the preconfigured "secure" configuration with an already built "credentials graph" that users TinkerGraph. You can run that example with:

```
$ bin/gremlin-server.sh conf/gremlin-server-secure.yaml
```

Take a good look at what's in `conf/gremlin-server-secure.yaml` and how it ties to the `conf/tinkergraph-credentials.properties` then make similar changes in your JanusGraph Server configuration. That should get you started.